# Border XML not loading dynamically in Android

Tags: android, css, xml, android-layout

I am trying to set a RelativeLayout border generated dynamically. For some reason, when I do it manually in the activity XML it works perfectly, but when I try to add it dynamically it doesn't show.

**border.xml located in drawables folder**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#000" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:bottom="1dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#fff" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**activity XML file**

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="5px"
            android:paddingTop="5px"
            android:background="@drawable/border">
```

**Code to add it directly and append it to an existing LinearLayout**

```
public void load(){

LinearLayout UsersContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.usersContainer);
RelativeLayout UserContainer = new RelativeLayout(this);
UserContainer.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
UserContainer.setPadding(0,5,5,0);
UserContainer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border);
UsersContainer.addView(UserContainer);
}
```

I would really appreciate your help! I have tried loading a TextView to the LinearLayout and it works fine. The RelativeLayout however does not show the border (it does load though!).

Comment: Why don't you keep the border defined in XML, then?

Comment: Why don't you set the border directly on the RelativeLayout?

Comment: Because I actually dont know how many I am going to have as I load many of them dynamically.

Comment: And what about the second question? Did you try it?

Comment: I dont know how to do that, I thought I needed to define the drawable separately and then use it as a background. I want the  RelativeLayout to have only a bottom black border.

Comment: Ok, so you want to add RelativeLayout dynamically to your LinearLayout and apply the border.xml as background, is that it?

Comment: Yeah! :) Thats exactly what I want

Comment: I'll answer shortly. Just one note: your variable names must always start with lower-case.

Comment: you would better use dp instead of 5px in relative layout\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need a little fix.

In your code code, change your `load()` method to:

```
LinearLayout usersLinear = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.usersContainer);
RelativeLayout userRelative = new RelativeLayout(this);
//you were setting your height value as RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, I changed it //to RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
userRelative.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
//apply padding
userRelative.setPadding(0,5,5,0);
userRelative.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border);
usersLinear.addView(userRelative);
```

So, your code was working, but you were not applying a proper height value to your dynamically generated `RelativeLayout`, and it was not showing on the layout,because it was empty (no child view inside it). With `MATCH_PARENT`, it will have the same height as its parent. You can play with these values to adjust to your case as you want. And do not forget the `Gravity` params you can also configure dynamically.